# Does Android (4.0 +) automatically sense what time zone the device is in and change the time display accordingly?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, clock, time-zones

The title pretty much states my question but mainly I want to know if I say hope a flight in NY to California will android pick up on the time difference between the time zones? Or do I Manually need to set this?

The reason I am asking is for an app I am developing and the way I see it adding duplicate code of something that android already has is pretty much re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on a network that is available on the location you are going to, you could check the `Automatic date and time` setting under `Date and time` settings. That should update the time accordingly.

Comment: Not all carriers have NITZ or some of the NITZ info are not fully parseable, depending on `rild` version and Android version! Even if the auto update is activated, it can fail!. The `rild` can be out of date, GB uses v3, ICS uses v6, it is continually changing. If rooted, could use NTP sync over wifi.